# Running TypeDoc on Windows generates no files and no errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, typedoc

I am attempting to use TypeDoc to generate documentation for a js app I am developing. For some reason, I can't get TypeDoc to output anything - files or errors.

To get to this point I installed TypeDoc inside the project folder:

```
npm install typedoc --save-dev
```

Then I opened PowerShell (also tried cmd) in admin in the project folder and attempted to run TypeDoc with several variations to see if I could get it to work:

- `node typedoc --help` throws an error stating the module cannot be found
- `node node_modules/typedoc --help` appears to run but does not produce any output
- `node node_modules/typedoc --out docs --mode modules ./` also appears to run but does not produce any output

I have tried a few other variations and can't seem to get any messages to the console or generate any files.

I am running Node v9.10.1 and TypeDoc 0.15.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably wanting to use `npx` which is included with recent versions of node. It will automatically look up the package you are trying to use (either using the local version or installing it to cache.

With that you should be able to run typedoc.

`npx typedoc --help`

Comment: Although this solves my issue, is there any explanation you can think of for why the commands I was running previously weren't working?

Comment: You weren't correctly accessing the node program. You could install typedoc globally `npm i -g typedoc` to allow accessing without invoking node manually. A script in package.json could also run `typedoc --help` without needing `node`